# Is it possible to put armor on a skeleton?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I've made a monster zoo and want to put armor on the skeletons.

How do I do so? Or do they just spawn that way?

Comment: If my answer helped, you can click the check mark to accept it.

Answer (score 7):

Simple, run a command using the `Equipment[]` tag, or whatever that JSON stuff is. Here's an example. You can add things onto it such as armor, mob heads, and it can hold any item.

```
/summon Skeleton {Equipment[{id:276},{id:313},{id:312},{id:311},{id:310}]}
```

This summons a Skeleton with full diamond armor, and a diamond sword. If you don't want the mob to have certain types of armor or items, you can just leave those brackets blank. If you want to learn more about commands, you can visit the the  [Wiki page on commands](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Commands).

Comment: +1 For helping increase awareness of the power of commands. I'd also like to mention that command blocks are useful for executing commands at the push of a button (literally).

Comment: @Pharap Yes, commands are quite useful, especially with JSON integrated into it.

Answer (score -1):

Also you can just use a dispenser and shoot it onto him it works great