# Can you put diamond armor on skeletons via command using Pocket Edition?

Tags: minecraft-commands, minecraft-bedrock-edition

I wanted to try and experiment with long jumps and bow spleef using arrows, but for that, I need skeletons.

I want to make sure that they don't take much damage with their bows and will remain with Flame enchanted bows and diamond armor

I found [this question](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/177702/is-it-possible-to-put-armor-on-a-skeleton) that would've helped me. But since I'm using Pocket Edition (Bedrock Mobile), it doesn't work.

Reasons?:

1. IDs on items doesn't actually exist in PE, only in Java.
2. The JSON line doesn't work because of the spacing. The formula of the `/summon` command is `/summon Entity x y z` and it doesn't give the `Equipment` form (probably because it is only supported in Java Edition).
3. Even if replacing the IDs by the supported names of the items from the `/give` command (an example would be `diamond_helmet`), it won't work.

Is there a way how I can do it in Pocket Edition using a command?

Answer (score 2):

Do:

```
/replaceitem entity @e[type=skeleton,r=5] slot.armor.chest 0 diamond_chestplate 1 0
```

That puts a diamond chestplate on the skeleton you are standing on. Use the following slots for the different armor pieces:

- `slot.armor.head`
- `slot.armor.chest`
- `slot.armor.legs`
- `slot.armor.feet`

Replace `diamond_chestplate` with the correct armor type. *Note: Minecraft will only allow items that are supposed to be on the player (i.e. armor, elytra, pumpkin, heads) on the player and it will fail if you try to have it wear something like a block.*